# Swift Alamofire RequestInterceptor - How to return the original error received from the server?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire RequestInterceptor for handling cases that the request is failed due to 401 unauthorized.
My Problem is, in cases which the error is not 401, instead of getting the original error from the server, I am getting:
requestRetryFailed unacceptableStatusCode.
Before using the interceptor I was able to JSON parse the result and get the error.
Here is my code:

```
class APIRequest {
    
    var method: HTTPMethod
    var path: String
    var params : Codable?
    let retryLimit = 2

    
    init(method : HTTPMethod, path : String, params : Codable?) {
        self.method = method
        self.path = path
        self.params = params
    }
    
    func requestWithAlamofire(with baseURL: URL) -> DataRequest {
        var params:[String: Any]!
        params = self.params?.dictionary ?? [:]
        debugPrint("request params: ", params)
        let urlString = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path).absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding ?? ""
        debugPrint(urlString)
        let url = URL(string: urlString) ?? baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)
        
        if self.method == .post || self.method == .put || self.method == .delete {
            return AF.request(url/*baseURL.appendingPathComponent(path)*/, method: self.method, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: httpHeader, interceptor: self).validate()
        }
        return AF.request(url, method: self.method, parameters: params, headers: httpHeader, interceptor: self).validate()
    }
}

extension APIRequest : RequestInterceptor {
    
    
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        var request = urlRequest
        guard let token = UserDefaultsManager.shared.getidToken() else {
            completion(.success(urlRequest))
            return
        }
        let bearerToken = "Bearer \(token)"
        request.setValue(bearerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        debugPrint("\nadapted; token added to the header field is: \(bearerToken)\n")
        completion(.success(request))
    }
    
    func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error,
               completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void) {
        guard let statusCode = request.response?.statusCode, statusCode == 401, request.retryCount < retryLimit else {
            completion(.doNotRetryWithError(error))
            return
        }
        debugPrint("\nretried; retry count: \(request.retryCount)\n")
        AWSProvider.authProvider.fetchAuthSession { isSuccess in
            isSuccess ? completion(.retry) : completion(.doNotRetry)
        }
    }
    

}
```

This is the class that handle the request result:

```
func sendWithAlamofire<T: Decodable>(apiRequest: APIRequest) -> Observable<T?> {
        let baseURL = URL(string:  BASE_URL)
        return Observable<T?>.create { observer in
            let task = apiRequest.requestWithAlamofire(with: baseURL!).responseData(completionHandler: { (data) in
                do {
                    switch data.result {
                    case .success(let successData):
                        debugPrint("success", JSON(successData))
                        debugPrint("statusCode" , data.response?.statusCode)
                        if let response = data.data {
                            if let statusCode = data.response?.statusCode, statusCode != 200 {
                                let err = NSError(domain: "", code: statusCode, userInfo: JSON(data.data ?? Data()).dictionaryObject)
                                observer.onError(err)
                            } else {
                                if response.isEmpty {
                                    observer.onNext(nil)
                                } else {
                                    let model: T = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data.data ?? Data())
                                    observer.onNext(model)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        debugPrint(error)
                        observer.onError(error)
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    debugPrint(error)
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
                observer.onCompleted()
            })
            return Disposables.create {
                task.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to process the response in the error case, don't return `.doNotRetryWithError`.  Just don't retry then process the response like you used to.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I got the same behavior on both cases. Before using the interceptor I process the result inside the success block and checked if the status code is other than 200. Now I got the requestRetryFailed unacceptableStatusCode inside the failure block. @JonShier

Comment: Yes, you've added a `validate()` call. If you want to parse the body data in spite of that error, it's still returned in your response handler, so just move your parsing outside the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can specific some case for that so it can bypass the validation of Interceptor.
For example in my case, i have `login` api sometime return 401, and client refuse to fix it and still want to parse the response of `login` to show to user. SO i have to create a list of status code which interceptor will treat it as success `[200, 201, 202]` but add a condition check for `login` endpoint to include `401`. Then the `session` will be like this

```
sessionManager.request(executableRequest).validate(statusCode: [200, 201, 202, 401]).responseDecodable
```

Also inside

```
func retry(_ request: Request, for session: Session, dueTo error: Error, completion: @escaping (RetryResult) -> Void)
```

I have to check for `login` endpoint to return as `doNotRetry`

```
if request.request is Login {
     return completion(.doNotRetry)
}
```

So it will return to result of `responseDecodable`